# Not able to insert string which contains '

Tags: php

I wrote a script to insert record in my DB. The only issue I am getting is when I try to store data which contains `'` character then the script does not work and it does not store anything in the DB. For example `John's Birthday` , `Amy's Home` etc . Any solution to this problem which allows special character like `'` to store in the DB and retrieving them without  any harm to security?

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Story (desc)
VALUES ('$mytext')");
```

Comment: @KA_lin Using PDO is not a solution, and `addslashes()` is a crude fix that is not character set aware, unlike `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, which is.

Comment: @MikeW If i use mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $mytext); then I cannot become a victim of SQL Injection? or the like. Also retrieving them won't create any harm to security too right?

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is specifically provided for this purpose. If you're properly escaping your input with it you're not likely to become a victim of an SQL Injection attack. I won't say 'never' since a second-level injection attack is sometimes possible even if you're escaping or using prepared statements. That depends on your code elsewhere.

Comment: @MikeW thanks for the explanation I got the point now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `mysqli_real_escape_string` is made specifically for this purpose. You problem is that quotes are being interpreted by MySQL as part of the query instead of values. You need to escape characters like this so they won't affect your query - this is what SQL injection is.

```
$mytext = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $mytext);
// continue with your query
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: hmmm interesting means if i use `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $mytext);` then I cannot become a victim of SQL Injection? or the like

Comment: Nope, but it's a start. Have a look at the manual for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

Filter the variable part of the query through [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).